# Multiple checkbox. Correct/incorrect

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('.next21').click(function(){

       if (($('.twoone :checked[data-correct]').length != 4)&&($('.twoone :checked[value="incorrect"]').length != 0)){
                instp.open();
                $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            }
       else if ($('.twoone :checked[data-correct]').length == 4) {
                $(".twoone").slideUp();
                $(".twotwo").slideDown();
            }     

    });
```

Does not work, this part of the code:
($('.twoone :checked[data-correct]').length != 4)

What to do?(

Comment: This would be a better question if you included your HTML containing the checkboxes and their attributes.

Comment: Solved


`
$('.next22').click(function(){
 
   if (($('.twotwo :checked[data-correct]').length != 4)||($('.twotwo :checked[value="incorrect"]').length != 0)){
         instp.open();
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        }
     else {
            $(".twotwo").slideUp();
            $(".three").slideDown();
        }

});`